# MVC 5 HTML helper for client side validation for value not in model

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm following the MVC tutorial here to add a search/filter textbox:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search

I've added the filter textbox to my page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p> Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
}
```

How do I perform client side validation on the textbox to ensure something was entered?

When you automatically created the controller and views based on a model, it creates this handy HTML helper:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Can something similar be used for a value not in your model or do you have to add custom jquery/html?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the direction everyone.  Just adding some more information now.  I've created a new class in my existing model:

```
public class SearchItem
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "This is my test error message")]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside the controller, I've created a partial view:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[AllowAnonymous]
public PartialViewResult Search()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Then I've created a new Search.cshtml with:

```
@model App.Models.SearchItem

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchString, "Search:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })</h4>
    <div class="col-md-10 input-max-width">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchString, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchString, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Then on my existing page, I add it with this:

```
@Html.Action("Search", "Items")
```

When I enter no text into the textbox and click the Search button, the page just refreshes and I get no client side validation.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="/Items/Index" method="post">    <div class="form-group">
    <h4><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SearchString">Search:</label></h4>
    <div class="col-md-10 input-max-width">
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="This is my test error message" data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="The SearchString field is required." id="SearchString" name="SearchString" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SearchString" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

Comment: You could add it to your model, apply `Required` to it, then let jquery unobtrusive apply the client side validation.

Comment: Just create a view model with property `string SearchString` and apply the `[Required]` attribute (otherwise you will need to manually add the necessary `data-val-*` attributes to your html and then duplicate the validation again on the server)

Comment: If you look two tutorials down in the list on the left, you see they have a tutorial titled "Adding Validation" ... http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: Also, use @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchString)

Comment: Just made an edit above which still doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you include `jquery-{version}.js`? - What error messages are you getting in the browser console